# CSS3 works on 1 2012 IIS (6.2) gateway and not the failover (same env)

Tags: html, css, cognos

I am using (Cognos) html report objects with CSS3, html5 and javascript.
Our dev server works like a champ - transitions are beautiful and consistent.

PQA on the other hand just sits there - no hover or transition. The code is an exact copy between servers.

Cognos dynamically adds the css / html to the page and renders as if the code were part of the report initially.  HTML5 has been working with Cognos RS since 2011 (as far as I know).

Here is the snippet that when embedded in cognos works fine on Dev and not on PQA.  Thinking there has got to be an IIS setting I missed between server configs.
***Keep in mind this gets embedded into a web app and runs fine in Dev but not PQA - it's not a syntax issue***

```
<STYLE >
div.ul
{
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
-webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: width 2s;
}
div.buttons
{
transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
background-color: red;
visibility:hidden;
}
div.ul:hover  
{
 width: 300px;
}
div.ul:hover .buttons 
{
background-color: green;
visibility:visible;
}
</STYLE>

<div class="ul" id="ul1">
<table  >
<tr>    
<td width="150px">
<div class="buttons" onmouseover="show2013();">2013
<input type="radio" name="curBudget" border="0"  style="background-color:#FF1493;border-width:    
0px;" onclick="hideOther()"  >
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideOther()
{
document.getElementById("ul1").style.display = "none";
}
function show2013() {
document.getElementById("cur11_1").style.display = "visible";       
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is a difference in the returned markup from both servers, have you identified what it is?

Comment: There is no difference between the 2 servers - the xml generated (which is how cognos works or what it shows us) is the same.

Comment: My point was that if you look at what's served to the browser there must be a difference as the behaviour is different, the difference may provide some insight

Comment: Help me out here - are you referring to the DOM explorer results in developer toolkit (using ie vs ff or chrome)?  I did not think to grab that and diff but will do. Thank you for your help - it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh 1 other thing - our gateways are different because we have a 2rd 3rd party tool - data clarity.  They serve up our mobile site (not very nicely at all - would not suggest it).  The site in their wrapper comes up fine on mobile - but not desktop.  That's where the css3 and html5 are just doing nothing.

Comment: Looking at the generated html brought to light that one gateway was using cgi and the other isapi.  Switching to isapi fixed the issue.  Thank you!